# Using Promises in node.js to avoid errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I would like to know if it is ok to include promises to catch errors and avoid stack error propagation into a node.js application.

I know that promises is used to stop the async nature of Javascript, but should I just use it for that purpose? Can't I put some promises in the start process for avoiding errors?

I'm thinking about changing my code from this:

```
var server = {
 create: function() {
  Configuration();
  Apps();
  Database();
  Routes();
 }
};
```

To this:

```
var server = {
 create: function() {
  Configuration().then(Apps).then(Database).then(Routes)
  .catch(function(error) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    process.exit(0);
  };
 }
};
```

Could some promises guru tell me the pros and cons of the changes in my code?

Basically, what the code does is:

```
Configuration -> turn configurations object global
Apps -> Initialize express configurations (uses, sets and engines)
Database -> Connect to Database
Routes -> Initialize routes, controllers and models
```

And I'm thinking about promisify other steps that are inside these four initials.

Thanks.

Comment: Are these functions `asynchronous`? If not, then you should stick with good old try and catch to handle errors. Promises don't "stop" the `async` nature of javascript. They are built on top of it.

Comment: Yes, they are asynchronous. Promises don't stop async??

Comment: No they don't, your code is still `asynchronous`, however they allow you to work on a `synchronous` way.

Comment: `they allow you to work on a synchronous way. ` ... that statement is just as misleading to anyone who thinks that promises can make async code sync

Comment: @user98293989823 Promises are basically just a different way of writing callbacks. Normally, you have something like `asyncCall(data, successCallback, errorCallback)`, with Promises, this is `asyncCall(data).then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback)`. The main advantage I see is that it makes your code much cleaner.